# conda install cartopy conflict

Tags: python, conda, cartopy

I have to install cartopy, here is what I've done:

```
[cwullu@dellsv ~]$ conda create -n test  
[cwullu@dellsv ~]$ source activate test  
(test) [cwullu@dellsv ~]$ conda install python=3.6
```

And after install some other packages, I start to install cartopy:

```
(test) [cwullu@dellsv ~]$ conda install -c conda-forge cartopy  
Fetching package metadata .............  
Solving package specifications: .  

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:  
  - cartopy -> python 2.7* -> libgcc-ng >=4.9  
  - cartopy -> python 2.7* -> libstdcxx-ng >=4.9  
  - python 3.6*  
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Is it means that cartopy is in conflict to python3.6?
And how can I solve this problem?
I have tried to install python 2.7 and then install cartopy, it can work. But when I import cartopy, it still raise some error.

Here are my total package in this env:

```
(test) [cwullu@dellsv ~]$ conda list
# packages in environment at /home/cwullu/anaconda3/envs/test:
#
blas                      1.0                         mkl
ca-certificates           2019.6.16            hecc5488_0    conda-forge
cartopy                   0.14.2              np111py35_1    conda-forge
certifi                   2016.2.28                py35_0
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_1    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.12.1                        1    conda-forge
freetype                  2.6.3                         1    conda-forge
geos                      3.4.2                         4    http://conda.binstar.org/unidata
icu                       58.2                          0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9b                            2    conda-forge
libffi                    3.2.1                         3    conda-forge
libgfortran               3.0.0                         1    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.14                          4    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.34                        0    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.0.8                         0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.5                         1    conda-forge
matplotlib                1.5.3               np111py35_2    conda-forge
mkl                       2017.0.3                      0
mock                      2.0.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   5.9                          10    conda-forge
nose                      1.3.7                    py35_2    conda-forge
numpy                     1.11.3                   py35_0
olefile                   0.46                       py_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.0.2o                        0    conda-forge
owslib                    0.18.0                     py_0    conda-forge
pbr                       5.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pillow                    4.0.0                    py35_1    conda-forge
pip                       9.0.1                    py35_1
proj4                     4.9.1                         1    http://conda.binstar.org/unidata
pyepsg                    0.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pyproj                    1.9.4                    py35_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      4.11.4                   py35_3    conda-forge
pyshp                     2.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
python                    3.5.4                         0
python-dateutil           2.8.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pytz                      2019.1                     py_0    conda-forge
qt                        4.8.7                         3
readline                  6.2                           0    conda-forge
requests                  2.13.0                   py35_0    conda-forge
scipy                     0.19.0              np111py35_0
setuptools                36.4.0                   py35_1
shapely                   1.5.17              np111py35_0    conda-forge
sip                       4.18                     py35_1    conda-forge
six                       1.11.0                   py35_1    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.13.0                        1    conda-forge
tk                        8.5.18                        0
wheel                     0.29.0                   py35_0
xz                        5.2.3                         0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11                        0    conda-forge
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Installing 1 program at a time with conda can lead to dependency conflicts. Try create new environment with some packages: 
`conda create -n cartopy_env python=3.5 cartopy`
conda will solve the possible conflict for you. But it will take longer time to install.

Comment: Thanks! I used this method, it seems that cartopy can be installed well. But this time I can not use python... It can be installed but I can not get into the python shell.

Comment: It displayed this message: "python: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.7' not found (required by /home/cwullu/anaconda3/envs/test2/bin/../lib/libpython3.5m.so.1.0)
"

Answer (score 0):

To best use `conda-forge`, you should make sure that `conda-forge` is first in your channels listing and that you have `channel_priority: strict` set.

```
$ cat ~/.condarc 
channel_priority: strict
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
```

these can be set from the command line like so:

```
$ conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
$ conda config --set channel_priority strict
```

I just tested and `conda create -n test python=3.6 cartopy` worked for me on linux64.

Comment: Thanks! But when I run "conda config --set channel_priority strict", it raised an error: "TypeCoercionError: The value 'strict' cannot be boolified.". How can I solve this? Thanks!

Comment: How old is your conda version? `conda list -n base conda`

Comment: my anaconda version is 4.4.0, conda is 4.3.21

Comment: You should really upgrade conda and also do my example `conda create` command, you tried to install python=3.6 into a python=2.7 env.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install cartopy with `pip` into your conda environment. Maybe there's no Python 3 conda package, but according to PyPI, several versions of Python 3 are supported. Not 3.6 though, but 3.5.

https://pypi.org/project/Cartopy/

Comment: Thanks! But I have tested to use pip and there was still some problems...